# How to change size of window tab font in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My computer is 4k display and the tab font is too tiny now. How to change the size of window tab font in as shown in this picture?
[image]

Answer (score 30):

The window.zoomLevel setting can be accessed using:
File > Preferences > Settings and search for "zoomlevel"

[VS Code Screenshot of window.zoomLevel Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpj4.png)

This setting appears to zoom everything in the window, except for the top menubar.

I use a zoomLevel of 0.5.

After changing it to 0.5, I reduced my setting for editor.fontSize, to avoid the fontsize in the code editor becoming too large.

An alternative to modifying window.zoomLevel in settings is to use Ctrl + and Ctrl - to modify window.zoomLevel in increments of 1.

(I don't think VS Code currently has any option to configure *only* the size of the font used for the tab names.)

Comment: Hmmm... no success with Visual Studio 2022 for Mac.  I'm not seeing Zoom Level under Preferences.  Thus my tabs fonts are still the same size.

Comment: @MichaelR Visual Studio 2022 settings are different than Visual Studio Code aka VS Code which is what is being referred to here.

Answer (score 2):

Please create a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3702) for this on the repository.