# How to customize font size of tab title in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The font size of tab title in visual studio is very small. Is there any way to customise the font size of title tab in visual studio code?

Comment: refer to this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805920/how-to-change-size-of-window-tab-font-in-visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805920/how-to-change-size-of-window-tab-font-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: The answers to that questions are not working in my case